# KENDOUI Grid - how to add class

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I initialize the table as follows:

```
<div id="ordersList"
       data-role="uigrid"
       data-scrollable="false"
       data-checkbox="true"
       data-pageable="true"
       data-class="zebra"
       data-bind="source: orders, events : { selectionChanged: selectionChanged }"
       data-columns="[
          <% if (isSeller) { %>
          { title: 'Покупатель', field: 'buyerName' },
          { title: 'GLN покупателя', field: 'buyerGln' },
          <% } else { %>
          { title: 'Продавец', field: 'sellerName' },
          { title: 'GLN продавца', field: 'sellerGln' },
          <% } %>
          { title: 'Номер заказа', templateId: 'col-template' },
          { title: 'Статус', field: 'status' }
          <% if (!isSeller) { %>
          ,{ title: '', templateId: 'col2-template', width: 35 }
          <% } %>
          ]"></div>
</div>
```

How to add the class to the table?
This variant does'n work - `data-class="paging-fix zebra"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uh ... did you try add it by usual way?

```
<div id="ordersList" class="MyClass"
    data-role="uigrid" 
    ...
```

[Here](http://dojo.telerik.com/afECe/16) you can see that class is added.

Comment: Need to add class only for the table

Comment: Check html code on the example page. Class is added to div transformed to the grid. You can manipulate with grid through that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, creating a grid whith an div, you can apply an Class direcly in your selector, if you preffer or if you having problems, you can append class to the widget Wrapper (something like : `Objectgrid.wrapper`) **after initialization**

Hope this help